# Address bar in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make a very (VERY) simple HTML page which contains a form with an input field, for the user to provide a URL. When the user enters a URL in this input field, e.g. `https://google.com`, the browser should navigate to that address.

It sounds very simple, but I couldn't find out how to do it.

Comment: Your question is a little too broad to answer, but this might get you going in the right direction: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Comment: why you need that when it already exists in almost all the browsers?

Comment: I'm planning to put it inside MOTDs where there's no address bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are interested in this, as a step in trying to understand some of the basics, not as any form of production code. In that vein, you could try this.

```html
<form id="myform" action="#">
  URL:<br>
  <input type="text" onChange="this.form.action=this.value" value=""><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Note that because code snippets run in iframes, sandboxing rules apply. So only stackoverflow urls will work in the live example.

Answer (score 1):

I made an example for you - using jQuery:

```js
// wait for DOM ready
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // set listener for keypress on the input field with class "input-url"
    $(".input-url").keypress(function (e) {
      // on enter press
      if (e.which == 13) {
 // get input value and set it as window.location
        window.location.replace($(this).val());
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input-url" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

With URL Validation.

HTML

```
<input type="url" id="url">
```

JS (without jQuery)

```
// Take the input element
const urlInput = document.querySelector('#url');

// Function to call on event listener
let redirectToUrl = function (e) {
    // If enter is pressed and If it is a proper URL
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && isURL(urlInput.value)) {
        window.location.replace(urlInput.value);
    }
}

// Function to validate URL using Regex
function isURL(url) {
    const expression = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/gi;
    const regex = new RegExp(expression);
    if (url.match(regex)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Add event listener to input field
urlInput.addEventListener('keypress', redirectToUrl);
```